# Making a visitor tracker in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, tracker

I've currently installed a plugin (https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker)

Which does the tracking thing, only I want to get unique visitors. I really don't know how to extract those from this package. Or how I should make one by my own.

I want them to return as a JSON object per month.

If someone could help me out with this?

I tried it using the `tracker_sessions` table, but that doesn't work well.

```
Route::get('admin/api', function(){

        $stats = DB::table('tracker_sessions')
          ->groupBy('created_at')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
          ->get([
            DB::raw('created_at as y'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as b')
          ]);

          return json_encode($stats);
    });
```

That returns something like this:

```
[{"y":"2016-05-22 21:17:17","b":1},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:17:27","b":1},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:17:28","b":2},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:17:29","b":1},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:17:31","b":1},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:17:33","b":1},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:18:10","b":1},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:18:11","b":2},{"y":"2016-05-22 21:18:13","b":1}]
```

Which is not good at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('admin/api', function(){

    $stats = DB::table('tracker_sessions')
      ->groupBy(DB::raw('CAST(created_at as DATE)'))
      ->orderBy(DB::raw('CAST(created_at as DATE)'))
      ->get([
        DB::raw('CAST(created_at as DATE) as y'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT ip_column) as b')
      ]
    );

    return json_encode($stats);
});
```

Comment: Hm... That's not what I want, I kinda want the unique visitors of `this month`. So All the unique visitors (by IP checked) per day over this month. So I can create a graph that shows the unique visits per day in this month.

Comment: Ok. Edited with `CAST(created_at as DATE)`.

Comment: Thanks, but Can I get another date format? Like `DD-MM-YYY`? Also It doesn't order on `client_ip`, but if I add `->groupBy('client_ip')` it groups everything together.... Like all days, but I want them separated from each other.

Comment: You may use `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y')` instead of `CAST(created_at as DATE)`. If you need to order by client_ip and dont want to group by client_ip, you may try to order by max(client_ip) if it is good in you case.

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/NkxQm is what I get now, that returns `[{"y":"22-05-2016","b":11},{"y":"23-05-2016","b":52}]`, but It actually needs to be `1` for the `b` in both cases, because I need to order/get only the result for 1 IP. So if I get 999999 records for 1 IP, it needs to say 1 and not 999999.

Comment: Ok. Edited. `COUNT(DISTINCT ip_column) as b`